# Add new icon to jQuery Easy UI

Tags: jquery, css, icons, jquery-easyui

I want to add new icons to my jquery easy UI, but I create a new class in the ribbon-icon.css and put the class on the data options and doesn't work.
Whats wrong in my code?
Code in the html:

```
 <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="name:'concurso', iconCls:'icon-concurso-large', iconAlign:'top',size:'large', plain:'true'">Concurso</a>
```

Code in the css:

```
.icon-concurso-large{
background:url('images/32/concurso.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it's old question, but as mentioned - "for future Googlers":

1. Put a new class in your CSS, for example:

   ```
   .icon-warning {
        background: transparent url("../img/warning.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
    }
   ```
2. Set iconCls to your class ("icon-warning" from above example)
3. Make sure that your CSS is loaded AFTER jquery-easy-ui's CSS (otherwise your class will by overwritten)

Comment: Thanks for the answer 

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into this while looking for something else, but for future Googlers...

Put your downloaded icon in `jqueryui/themes/icons/`. (I use the 16x16 icons from [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com))

Add your class definition to `jqueryui/themes/icon.css`

Answer (score 0):

If it serves someone, don't make comments before declare the class in the css.